# Is using SVC for detection problems is the right choice?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, svm, scikit-learn

I have an NLP problem(fake news detection) and I used the code below, can I use svc for classification? and is my cross-validation accurate?

```
k = 10
kf = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=k, random_state=None)
svc=SVC(probability=True, C=100)
y_pred3=cross_val_predict(svc,scaled_X,y,cv=kf)
result3 = cross_val_score(svc , scaled_X, y, cv = kf)
print("Avg accuracy: {}".format(result3.mean()))
conf_mat3=confusion_matrix(y_pred3,y)
conf_mat3
print(classification_report(y, y_pred3))
```

the classification report:

[image]